# Declare as local var will break a function and log out "1: number expected"

Tags: variable, function, variable-substitution, oh-my-zsh

```
function projectopen {
    local di_files=(*.xcworkspace */*.xcworkspace *.xcodeproj */*.xcodeproj)

    # open first exsit file
    ls -d -f -1 $di_files  2>/dev/null \
    | head -1 \
    | xargs open
}
```

I write a shell function to quick open `xcworkspace` in terminal. But when I declare `di_files` as a `local` var, then the function is broken， and log

> projectopen:1: number expected

I use zsh on Mac OS. Why this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: how did you declare `di_files`? you shouldn't have any problems making your array variable local to the function

Comment: I update the function.@the_velour_fog

Comment: then I suspect there is something else going on and its probably that `ls` command. I would try removing or commenting out the `ls` command. then re-run your `projectopen` function defintion. I think you should find its ok. if so, then your could address the `ls` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In older versions of `zsh` you cannot initialise an array with `local` (or `typeset`/`declare`) like that, you need to separate it, e.g.

```
local -a di_files # explicit array
di_files=( ... )
```

The feature to permit declaration and array assignment together was added in v5.1.

I believe the error you see is because `zsh` is treating the initialisation as scalar and `()` as a glob qualifier.

You can also probably replace your elaborate pipeline with the simpler

```
open "${di_files[1]}"
```

Finally, including handling for no matching files:

```
function projectopen {
  setopt local_options nullglob
  local di_files=(*.xcworkspace */*.xcworkspace *.xcodeproj */*.xcodeproj)

  # open first existing file
  [ -n "${di_files[1]}" ] && open "${di_files[1]}"
}
```

With the `nullglob` option each glob expansion which matches no files is replaced with an empty string (I suspect you may have `nonomatch` set, a related option).

Comment: Great answer. But `ls` also excluded none existed files for me, any improve to your suggestions.